# Google cloud debugger repo-info file location in simple jar

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-debugger

A simple Java application is packaged in JAR format. It doesn't have the location 'WEB-INF/classes/' in it. Is it possible to customize location of source-context.json file, required by cloud-debugger through some environment variable.

If not, is there any other workaround to get it working except manually adding this location in the jar in every build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you run your application on a VM (not on AppEngine). In this case you can put source-context.json file in any directory within the class path.